# Image will not display inline with text within parent div

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, display

I have a parent div that contains text and a logo. These two elements are supposed to appear next to each-other, on the same line.

Despite having floated both elements to the left, adding code to have both image and parent container display inline, and having made sure the parent element is wide and tall enough to contain the image, the image is collapsing under the text.

HTML:

```
<div class="heading"><h1>Stanford Connection</h1><img src="tree-logo.gif" alt="Stanford Logo" id="logo"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
.heading {
width: 800px;
background-color: #9A0000;
color: white;
font-size: 20pt;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
float:left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't truly floated **both** elements to the left. You've floated `.heading` and `#logo` to the left, but floated elements should be **siblings**. As such, `.heading` would float to the left of any sibling element, and `h1` isn't set to `float` at all.

To align your images, all you need to do is float `h1` to the left as well:

```css
.heading {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #9A0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1, #logo {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h1>Stanford Connection</h1><img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Stanford Logo" id="logo" /></div>
```

Note that depending on where **exactly** you want the image to sit, `display: inline-block` may suit better.

Hope this helps! :)